# Running multiple tasks with progress report

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, c#-4.0

I have inherited a Winforms application in .NET 4 (I cannot change this). The application runs several tasks in parallel using TPL. First, a Task is created and from that task many more tasks are generated which do complex calculations. The main Task is waiting with `WaitAll(tasks)`.

The problem is that these little calculation tasks report progress to the main form, in each progress report the application calls `BeginInvoke()` to update the progress bar but it is updated only after all the tasks are finished. I believe the problem is that the main Task runs on the UI thread and by calling `WaitAll()` it blocks that thread so the `BeginInvoke()` calls are piling up on the event loop.

What is the correct approach in this case?

Reading other SO answers it seems that I cannot force a Task to run on a ThreadPool thread so I am inclined to replace the main Task with a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: The correct approach depends on the reason why you need to do a WaitAll(). However, I think in most cases using a background thread for waiting for all tasks to end should work.

Comment: I need to WaitAll because I need to do more things when the main Task is finished (it has ContinueWith() call).

Comment: Use a background worker thread then. One way to do it is like suggested by Kev's answer for example. (Although this behaviour TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning is confirmed by Microsoft for .NET 4.x, it is not guaranteed behaviour for future .NET version. But then again it is somewhat unlikely that this will be changed, since it is a 'confirmed implementation detail' ;-) )

Comment: I tried all suggested solutions and ended up using a BackgroundWorker. It works perfectly. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

setting the option TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning on your initial task will cause it to run on a separate thread (not a thread pool thread)

Comment: Actually I tried that and it didn't work. The Task still run on the main thread.

Comment: as much as I tried I couldn't actually get a task to run on the same thread as the ui thread in a sample app I created on my machine. Rich Newman has a sample on his site that may be what you're looking for. http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/why-starting-a-new-task-in-the-task-parallel-library-tpl-doesnt-always-start-a-new-thread/

Comment: In my case it always runs on the UI thread. I tired changing the options and the scheduler but it sill ran on the UI thread.